# PHP Html special chars prevent "&" from getting converted twice

Tags: php, html

I want to make sure every special character in my data is already converted to html entities using [htmlspecialcharacters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) , but then i noticed that in every replacement of special character to html entities , it has the "&" symbol , meanwhile the "&" symbol itself is replaced with `&amp;` .

So how do i use htmlspecialcharacters multiple times on same data without getting "&" converted multiple times.

Example :
No   conversion : `&`
1st  conversion : `&amp;`
2nd  conversion : `&amp;amp;`

Comment: "*So how do i use htmlspecialcharacters multiple times on same data*" ... short answer is, you do not apply that more than once. I mean, why would you? You should NOT be storing data in a db like that, you should only be using that (once) when outputting html to a client.

Comment: Hmm , maybe i need to re-think about the design , you're right . But there is no warning in the php web to not use it twice , so my question still remain.

Comment: Well, in defense of the php manual, it cannot cover all cases of how NOT to use something ;-)

Comment: Its the same rule with many of those encoders... don't do them twice. Like, dont use `urlencode` twice on the same value. Dont do `json_encode` twice, dont do `htmlentities` etc. Because you simply end up mangling the data to where it becomes a real hassle to back-step on.